# Finding the path of a negative weight cycle using Bellman-Ford

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I wrote a program which implements Bellman-Ford, and identifies when negative weight cycles are present in a graph. However what I'm actually interested in, is given some starting vertex and a graph, which path do I actually trace to get to the original vertex having traveled a negative amount.

So to be clear say I have a graph with vertexes, a, b, c, and d and there is a negative cycle between a, b, and d, then when I check for negative weight cycles

```
// Step 1: initialize graph
   for each vertex v in vertices:
       if v is source then distance[v] := 0
       else distance[v] := infinity
       predecessor[v] := null

   // Step 2: relax edges repeatedly
   for i from 1 to size(vertices)-1:
       for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:
           if distance[u] + w < distance[v]:
               distance[v] := distance[u] + w
               predecessor[v] := u

   // Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles
   for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:
       if distance[u] + w < distance[v]:
           "Graph contains a negative-weight cycle"
```

Instead of it just telling me that a negative cycle is there, I would like it to tell me, go from `a -> b -> d -> a`.  After the relaxing step what do I have to change in my check for negative weight cycles to get it to output this information?

- [Here](http://blog.alirabiee.com/?p=576) is the best information I've been able to find, but I'm still having trouble making sense of it.
- Also [this](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/f05/hw5.pdf) which suggests that I need to run breadth first search on the predecessor array to find the information, but I'm not exactly sure where to start (what do I queue first?)
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282427/interesting-problem-currency-arbitrage) is a stack overflow question which shows how to find one of the nodes in the path.

Comment: Just to clarify, is $a\xrightarrow{1} b \xrightarrow{-2} c \xrightarrow{-1} b \xrightarrow{1} a$ a (negative) cycle? And are you looking for the most efficient algorithm or just a working algorithm (but with a not so good complexity) is enough?

Comment: I would prefer the most efficient, but it dons't have to be. At the same if it's like $O(n^2)$ time on top of bellman ford then I dont want that either. I know that the predisessor array has the information, so really I'm asking how do I extract it. And more like a->b = 1, b->d = -3, d->a = 1, but really just any negative weight cycle

Comment: We already have a question on this topic: [Getting negative cycle using Bellman Ford](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/getting-negative-cycle-using-bellman-ford). Does that thread answer your question? If not, please edit your question to state what you still need answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Kleinberg–Tardos, you want to run Bellman–Ford for *n* iterations and find a cycle in the predecessor array.

To find a cycle in the predecessor array, start by coloring every node white. For each node *u* in an arbitrary order, set *v* := *u*, and, while *v* is white and has a predecessor, recolor *v* gray and set *v* := predecessor[*v*]. Upon exiting the loop, if *v* is gray, we found a cycle; loop through again to read it off. Otherwise, none of the gray nodes are involved in a cycle; loop through again to recolor them black.

Comment: Some points of confusion. by "every node u" you mean, for every node u in predecessor? What do you mean by "while v is white and has a predecessor"? and what does it mean to set `v := predecessor[v]`?  Thanks for the answering - @David Eisenstat

Comment: := is the assignment operator. The while condition is meaningful because *v* changes. I meant *every* node *u*, though it would suffice to consider only the ones with non-null predecessors.

Comment: I was not questioning what := means but rather what `predecessor[v]` is, and why its garnered to have a place in the predecessor array?

Comment: @Loourr predecessor[*v*] is the tail of the arc most recently relaxed among those having head *v*, just like in your pseudocode for B–F.

Comment: So in the step `for i from 1 to size(vertices)-1:` do I want to be doing `for i from 1 to size(vertices)`? and I'm still not sure what you mean by v "has a predecessor".

Comment: Yes to your question. "Has a predecessor" means predecessor[*v*] is non-null.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat  how do we know that the cycle we found is of a negative weight one? seems to me like this approach finds any random cycle in the graph?

Comment: @brucebanner Let's reweight the arc lengths from as $\ell'(u\rightarrow v)=\ell(u\rightarrow v)+d(u)-d(v)$, where $d$ is the Bellman–Ford distance labeling. Reweighting preserves cycle lengths (see also Johnson's algorithm). When Bellman–Ford inserts an arc into the predecessor array, its $\ell'$-length is zero. This length decreases if $u$'s distance label decreases, but it can't increase without evicting $u\rightarrow v$. Hence the cycle can't have positive length. It has negative length since, if $u\rightarrow v$ was last inserted, then $d(v)$ decreased, and the following arc goes negative.