# Is finding negative cycle vertices NP complete?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, shortest-path

I was trying to find all the negative cycle vertices using the Bellman–Ford algorithm using [this paper solution 7.1(b)](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/ps7sol.pdf) in $O(V)$ by tracing back the predecessor subgraph.It is also stated in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/getting-negative-cycle-using-bellman-ford) too. But then while googling I found another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720689/finding-all-vertices-on-negative-cycles) it is proved that finding negative cycle vertices are NP complete. So what is it actually?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear.

There is a tremendous difference between: (a) print out one example of a negative cycle, if one exists, (b) print out all negative cycles.

The former can be done in polynomial time using Bellman-Ford.  The latter cannot, as there could be exponentially many cycles, so it could take exponential time.  (The latter is not NP-complete, as the problem is not even in NP.)

The solution you link to is solving problem (a).